# Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 Continuously Uploading Same Records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a very simple setup using MSF from one client PC to one remote PC. Both are running SQL Server 2008 Express. The purpose is simply to send the data from a local server where the data is being collected at a competition to a web server for display.

However, this weekend I hit a situation where the local database is now continuously uploading 4 records to the remote database.  There are no error messages at this point and the sync apparently completes, but next time I run it again, it reports 4 records uploaded, even though there have been
no changes to the local database.

The data is transferred over a 3/4G link and there are occasionally dropouts on the link, but in the past Sync has recovered on the next iteration.  The only error message I saw that was unusual was "Cannot Enumerate Changes at the RelationalSyncProvider for table'Horses'."  Ironically this is one table that doesn't change during the day! But it does contain 4 records - hmmm.

I have tried backup and restore to another SQL instance on my development machine (SQL Server 2008 R2), have run fixup and then Sync to the remote and I get the same situation of 4 records uploaded (and now 1 downloaded), with no errors, but again the same record counts every time I run - and I know nothing is being updated.

As far as I can tell the data is in Sync as I can't see any obvious anomalies, but that is hard to be certain of.

So ...

1. Can I tell which records are the issue/being uploaded?
2. What can I do to ensure the data has in fact synced?
3. What can I do to "reset" so that the two databases know they are actually in Sync, preferably short of backup and restore!

Comment: you can enable Sync Fx tracing to see what's happening. you might want to subscribe to ApplyChangesFailed event too so you can check if there's an error applying the changes.

Comment: Thanks JuneT. I turned on tracing and this allowed me to see the affected table. (wasn't Horses!) I was then able to see that in fact the data was not in sync. I do subscribe to 'ApplyChangesFailed' and there were no errors just the continuous attempt to upload 4 records on each Sync. Interestingly there were 'WARNINGS' in the trace that suggested deleted data not being updated. Looking at the tables and tracking tables, I seem to have ended up with invalid tracking 'tombstone' records - but how I have no idea.  ...

Comment: In the case of this table, I could recreate the records, so my ultimate solution was to delete all the data in the affected tables on both client and server and to delete all the tracking records for those tables.  I was then able to re-create the data and sync successfully. However, there would have been other data/tables where that would not have been an option and I am worried that I still really have no idea how the data got into this state and how to prevent it.

Comment: the tracking table is updated via triggers, so if you happen to do operations that dont fire triggers, the tracking table will be out of sync.